# Why doesn't a levitating superconductor generate usable electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, superconductivity

Why doesn't a super cooled superconductor generate usable electricity due to the phenomenon of electromagnetic induction when placed upon a magnet? I basically mean, why can't it create electricity by using the [Meissner effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect) and electromagnetic induction?

Answer (score 1):

What a superconductor in a magnetic field does is create (by Lenz's Rule) a current that creates a magnetic field which in turn pushes the external field outside of the volume of the superconductor. Since such a material has no resistance, you have no heat losses that would decrease the internal current. To answer your question, a superconductor does produce electricity in a magnetic field, but that is used to levitate it.

Comment: can this electricity be used for other purposes other than levitation ?

Comment: You could use it in the same way that coils of copper wire are used in a generator. It is fundamentally nothing different, only that the resistance is zero. You might have seen that a magnet falls slowly, like in a viscous fluid, when [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BeFoz3Ypo4) it is falling through a copper tube. So, by building a generator that uses superconducting wires instead of copper wires, you end up with a higher efficiency, which is partly offset by the power you need to cool the superconductor down to when it reaches that superconducting state.

Comment: So is there any material that does not need low temp to make transion to superconductor ?

Comment: There is a lot of research going on at the moment to find a superconductor at room temperature. So far, "high temperature superconductors" range around something like -150°C, so this is still pretty cold. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity#mediaviewer/File:Sc_history.gif)

Comment: Thanx @andynitrox u answer all of my questions thanks man . Btw can I have ur email or something ?